# Is this expression for $\int e^{\cos(x)} dx$ using infinite trigonometric series correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, numerical-methods

TL;DR:
I think I can show that
$$\begin{align}\int e^{\cos(x)} dx = 
x\cdot \ I_{0}( 1) \ &+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sum _{k=0}^{n}\frac{\sin( x( 2k-2n-1))}{k!\cdot ( 2n-k+1) !\cdot ( 2k-2n-1) \cdot 2^{2n}} \\[4pt]
&+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\sin( x( 2k-2n))}{k!\cdot ( 2n-k) !\cdot ( 2k-2n) \cdot 2^{2n-1}} +C
\end{align}$$

And Desmos seems to suggest I have it right: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sdctneqnuc

Hi! I'm an undergrad engineer at UNCC and somewhat of a hobbyist and I enjoy finding solutions to non elementary integrals. Unfortunately I don't have anyone to review my work. I don't know if this has been solved before as there as several related Bessel functions, but even if I didn't break new ground with this one I had fun doing it regardless. I may eventually take the time to type out a proof but I think for the time being I'd rather just share my solution and the general steps I took to get there. I have some concerns about removing the floor function in the final solution but it seems to provide the same output and limits. Please let me know if I made a mistake, and if it's correct and worth having further reviewed I could also use some advice there as well!

---

Beginning by using the exponential form of $\cos (x), \frac{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}{2}$, we can obtain the following summations to expand integer powers of $\cos (x)^{n}$ into a series of terms with decreasing arguments

For odd $n:$ $$\cos ^{n}(x)=\left(\frac{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}{2^{n}}\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right) \cdot \frac{\cos (x(n-2 k))}{2^{n-1}}$$

For even $n:$ $$\cos ^{n}(x)=\left(\frac{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}{2^{n}}\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right.}\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right) \cdot \frac{\cos (x(n-2 k))}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{\left(2\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\right) !}{\left(\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) !\right)^{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

Now substituting $\cos (x)$ for $x$ in the taylor series of $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n !}$ and modifying the previous summations, we can obtain $$e^{\cos (x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2 n} \cdot n !^{2}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\cos (x(2 n-2 k+1))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k+1) ! \cdot 2^{2 n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\cos (x(2 n-2 k))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k) ! \cdot 2^{2 n-1}}$$

This now becomes the fairly simple integral:
$$\int e^{\cos (x)} d x=\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2 n} \cdot n !^{2}} d x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int \frac{\cos (x(2 n-2 k+1))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k+1) ! \cdot 2^{2 n}} d x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int \frac{\cos (x(2 n-2 k))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k) ! \cdot 2^{2 n-1}} d x$$

And for the final solution:
$$\int e^{\cos (x)} d x=x \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2 n} \cdot n !^{2}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\sin (x(2 k-2 n-1))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k+1) ! \cdot(2 k-2 n-1) \cdot 2^{2 n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin (x(2 k-2 n))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k) ! \cdot(2 k-2 n) \cdot 2^{2 n-1}}+C$$

or
$$\int e^{\cos (x)} d x=x \cdot I_{0}(1)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\sin (x(2 k-2 n-1))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k+1) ! \cdot(2 k-2 n-1) \cdot 2^{2 n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin (x(2 k-2 n))}{k ! \cdot(2 n-k) ! \cdot(2 k-2 n) \cdot 2^{2 n-1}}+C$$

Additionally: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{\cos (x)} d x=2 \pi \cdot I_{0}(1)$, and intriguingly $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\cos (x)} d x=\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot\left(L_{0}(1)+I_{0}(1)\right)$

Where $I_{0}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and $L_{0}(x)$ is the modified Struve function

[(Transcribed from screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQJ1.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I transcribed it for you using a program (mathpix) which may have introduced errors, so please check

Comment: I appreciate that! I'll check through and use it in the future!

Comment: If Desmos says it is correct, then it is probably correct. However, what you should ask yourself is 'is this useful?'. While it may be interesting, I feel the that in practice the RHS would be far more cumbersome to work with then the LHS. If the integral has some sort of physical meaning and arose in practice, the particular identities might be of use.

Comment: While I could see it arising in complex analysis, differential equations or electrical engineering, this was largely just to challenge myself. I mainly just wanted to have my work checked, and share on the off chance it may prove useful. But I agree, there's plenty of numeric alternatives that are far more useful when it comes to simply making calculations. I appreciate the input!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, analytic forms can be very useful, in particular it allowed you to derive values in terms of Bessel functions that would otherwise be far from obvious. And who knows - perhaps there are some interesting problems out there in which the integral arises and the form you derived comes of use. But yes, I think in general there are asymptotic and/or numerical approximations of the LHS which would be more effective.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for comments.*

We have
$$e^{\cos(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\cos^n(x)}{n!}$$

Without any restriction,
$$I_n=\int \cos^n(x)\,dx=-\frac{\sin (x) \cos ^{n+1}(x) }{(n+1)
   \sqrt{\sin ^2(x)}}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

$$J_n=\int_0^t \cos^n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}{(n+1)\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}-\frac{\sin (t) \cos ^{n+1}(t) }{(n+1)
   \sqrt{\sin ^2(t)}}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};\cos ^2(t)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {J_n}{n!}=\frac{\pi}{2}   (\pmb{L}_0(1)+I_0(1))-$$
$$\frac{\sin (t)}{\sqrt{\sin ^2(t)}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos ^{n+1}(t)}{(n+1)!}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};\cos ^2(t)\right)$$ from which the results for the  particular cases you mentioned.

Comment: I have a similar problem I would like to solve,  but substitution of -$\pi$ makes $I_n$ [indeterminate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28cos%5E%281+%2B+n%29%28x%29+2F1%281%2F2%2C+%281+%2B+n%29%2F2%2C+%283+%2B+n%29%2F2%2C+cos%5E2%28x%29%29+sin%28x%29%29%2F%28%281+%2B+n%29+sqrt%28sin%5E2%28x%29%29%29%2C+x%3D-pi). The substitution limit exists though. Also you can rewrite it in terms of a simple ratio of gamma functions also.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I saw your problem and, guess what ? .... I gave upi ! Sorry for that since it is a very interesting one which I follow. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks, but you did not have to mention the problem.