# Integration of $\exp(\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

I would like to integrate:
$$\int_0^{1}  \operatorname{e}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
I tried to make a change of variable $\sqrt{1-x^2}\rightarrow X$ but I get:
$$\int_0^{1} \frac{e^X X}{\sqrt{1-X^2}} \, dX=[-e^X\sqrt{1-X^2}]_0^1+\int_0^{1} e^X\sqrt{1-X^2}dX $$
which is not easier...

Could you help me to do so please ?

Comment: By substituting $x=\sin u$, you may reduce the integral to a special value of the modified Bessel function of the 1st kind, see the [integral representation of $I_1$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E3). This also hints that your integral is likely impossible to write in an elementary closed form.

Comment: Most integrands of the form $e^{f(x)}$ have no closed-form antiderivatives.

Comment: $1-x^2$ has roots $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = -1$ and has a leading coefficient $a=-1$. So perform the euler substitution $$x=\frac{a\beta-\alpha t^2}{a-t^2}=-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and assuming I am not mistaken, we have $$\int_0^1 e^\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = 4\int_0^1 e^{2t/(t^2+1)} \frac t{(t^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$ And now we can sub $t=\tan (u/2)$ so the exponent reduces to $\sin(u)$.

Comment: Actually, nvm about my substitutions. They are effectively the same (but just more elaborate) as $x = -\cos u$ which leads nowhere lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $x=\sin(t)$, you are left with
$$\int_0^{1}  e^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} e^{\cos(t)}\, \cos(t)\,dt$$ Now, have a look at my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178586/is-this-expression-for-int-e-cosx-dx-using-infinite-trigonometric-series/4184973#4184973) and I am sure that you will percieve the complexity of your problem (notice that using the expansion, the two problems are identical). Taking into account the bounds, the exact result is
$$\int_0^{1}  e^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma(n+1) \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}=\frac \pi 2  (\pmb{L}_{-1}(1)+I_1(1))$$ where appear Struve and Bessel functions.

Now, you can make quite good approximations using Padé approximant for the integrand. A simple one (built around $x=0$) would be
$$ e^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sim e \frac{13 x^4-54 x^2+48}{-2 x^4-30 x^2+48}$$ Write it a
$$ e \frac{13 x^4-54 x^2+48}{-2 x^4-30 x^2+48}=-\frac {13e}2\frac {(x^2-a)(x^2-b)}{(x^2-c)(x^2-d)}$$ with
$$a=\frac{27-\sqrt{105}}{13}\qquad b=\frac{27+\sqrt{105}}{13}\qquad c=-\frac{\sqrt{321}+15}{2}\qquad d=\frac{\sqrt{321}-15}{2}$$ and use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac {(x^2-a)(x^2-b)}{(x^2-c)(x^2-d)}=\frac{a b-a c-b c+c^2}{(c-d) (x^2-c)}+\frac{-a b+a d+b d-d^2}{(c-d) (x^2-d)}+1$$ and you will end with one arctangent and one hyperbolic arctangent.

The numerical result
$$\int_0^1 e \frac{13 x^4-54 x^2+48}{-2 x^4-30 x^2+48}\,dx=2.24770$$ while numerical integration gives
$$\int_0^1  e^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=2.24395$$ that is to say a relative error of $0.17$%.