# How are contributions to mathematics reviewed/published?

Tags: soft-question, research

Let's say you're a hobbyist who's seemingly found a novel identity/solution/method or other general contribution to some field of mathematics. What you don't know however is:

1. If you're actually the first to discover it
2. If it is useful
3. If it isn't useful, is it still worth having reviewed?
4. How to have it reviewed
5. How protective should you be of your finding?
6. If it is useful, how do you ensure you're accredited for it?
7. If, how and when you should post it on stack exchange

While I am asking for generalized advice I'll offer some background for context: I'm an engineering student, and I enjoy trying to find solutions to non-elementary integrals via functional analysis, complex analysis, combinatorial methods, etc. simply because I like the challenge and I've learned some fascinating things about other fields of mathematics I wouldn't normally be exposed to. With that being said, I may have managed to find a solution to a couple of non-elementary integrals and while I'm aware they have limited application, I'd still like to know if my work is correct and worth sharing, and maybe even get credit if it would land me a scholarship or something. The last part may be simple wishful thinking, but who knows?

Comment: Are you an undergraduate?

Comment: If you are an engineering student, I presume that you most likely have access to math faculty. Consult them.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not entirely sure what this implies but I only brought up my education to establish that while I have some mathematical background (Being an undergrad electrical engineering student with a mathematics minor), my work is not school related or part of any kind of organized research, nor am I familiar with how work is published

Comment: Typically, at least in past decades (e.g. before the internet), things like this would be sent to one of the many mathematics magazines/journals that had problems and solutions sections, and would not have been something you'd "try to publish". There have been so many integral evaluations in such columns in the past 200+ years that it's extremely doubtful anything you could come up with is truly new, but that's not really what's relevant for something like this, but rather whether anyone now recognizes it and whether anyone finds it of interest.

Comment: @DonThousand Fair enough. Until recently covid had made this rather difficult

Comment: @DietrichBurde As for the problems in reference, the ones I've attempted don't have solutions listed on Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica, Wikipedia or listed otherwise anywhere else I've found. I Posted one of them earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4240329/914955)

Comment: Short answer: If you found/discover a new thing/method/solution (e.g. famous problem) then you can publish it in ArXiv.

Comment: You may find this book worth looking over: [**An Introduction to the Operations with Series**](https://books.google.com/books?id=IJttAAAAMAAJ) by Isaac Joachim Schwatt (1924; reprinted with corrections by Chelsea Publishing Company in 1962). A google-books .pdf file of the 1924 edition is freely available where I'm at.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That was a great recomendation, I'm not certain if my solution was listed in their but given the range of similar problems I certainly wouldn't be surprised! What is surprising to me is how little of this is available on resources like wolfram

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of these things will require advice or scrutiny from a mathematician with experience in the field.  Since you are a university student, you should have easy access to a number of academics in the mathematics faculty, who regularly publish papers on mathematics.  I recommend speaking to one of them directly about your idea, but in the meantime, here is some general advice.

> What you don't know however is:
>
> 1. If you're actually the first to discover it.

That is something that we would typically find out by doing a "literature review", where we look at other papers/textbooks in the topic and see if we can find the result.  For this part, seeking review by an experienced mathematician in the field will probably be helpful, since they may recognise the result, and if they don't, that goes some way towards suggesting that it might be new.

If you perform a literature review on the matter, one of two things will happen.  Either you will find that the result is already published, or you will not find it.  In the latter case you would typically seek publication of your result, cite relevant literature in the general field, and report that you were unable to find the result in any of the existing literature.  Reviewers for the journal will then scrutinise this, and they will be a second check on whether it is an original result.  (And if you are like I was in grad-school, you will get a nice polite desk rejection from a helpful journal editor alerting you to the non-originality of your work!)

> 2. If it is useful.

That is something that requires professional judgment, but if you can point out an applied use for the result (where it performs better than other approaches), then obviously that shows that it is useful.  The best thing to do here would be to see if you can form an applied example of your result, showing that it can be used to solve a practical problem.

On this point, it is also worth noting that papers on *non-original* mathematical results can still be useful if they provide an alternative proof of the result that is new.  Papers can also be useful as educational publications even if neither the results nor their proofs are original, so long as they simplify a problem, or present it more clearly than existing works, or provide some useful insight that improves understanding.

> 3. If it isn't useful, is it still worth having reviewed?

Maybe, maybe not.  There is a history of mathematical results being published that were not perceived at the time as having any useful applications, but later came to have useful applications in unexpected ways.  This was particularly so in early number theory.  In order to form a view on whether "non-useful" mathematics is worth having reviewed, you might wish to read G.H Hardy's famous work, [*A Mathematician's Apology*](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf).

> 4. How to have it reviewed.

Before getting to this point, you will need to write up your work in a professional mathematics paper written in an appropriate form.  This would usually entail some context and literature review, and then clear presentation of your results and proof, and discussion/examples of applications.  Once you get to this point you can submit your work to an academic journal appropriate to the paper.  If you are not sure where to submit, ask a mathematician at your university, look at where other papers on the topic have been published, and browse some articles in possible target journals.

Once you have written your paper and identified an appropriate journal, read their guidelines for submission and go through their submission process.  Typically your paper will first go to an editor for an initial "desk review" and if they like it then they will send it out to independent referees for a full review.  Rejections in this process are common (even if your paper is good) and so ---assuming your work is publishable--- you might need to make revisions and try a few journals.

> 5. How protective should you be of your finding?

You can't simultaneously publish your findings and also be protective of them, so you will have to make a choice of what you want to do.  If you are particularly concerned about having your result "stolen" then you can publish the basics of it (e.g., theorem and proof) on a website or arXiv paper to establish precedence, but it is probably premature for this.  It would be best to at least find out if it is a new result first.

> 6. If it is useful, how do you ensure you're accredited for it?

If the result is original and useful then it should be publishable, and the authorship of your work will automatically give you credit for the work.  Again, if you are particularly worried about having your result "stolen", you can publish the basics of it (e.g., theorem and proof) on a website or arXiv paper to establish precedence.

> 7. If, how and when you should post it on stack exchange.

This depends on whether or not your work is amenable to a simple Q&A appropriate for this site.  Some results are sufficiently simple that they can serve as a useful Q&A  post, but many research results are more complicated (or voluminous) than is appropriate for this site.  In any case, posting your result as a Q&A on this site would serve the function of establishing initial publication, and subjecting your work to critical scrutiny by experts.  If you think this is a good idea then presumably an appropriate time to do so would be when you have a clearly formulated question, and an answer consisting of a theorem and proof.  It is possible, but I think unlikely, that this might undermine publication in a journal.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

##### Write it, submit it, and find out!

I'm in a similar situation - I am an amateur mathematician and I had an idea I wanted published, and was successful!  My paper was "[Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3459227)" and it was published in "Dynamics of Continuous, Discrete and Impulsive Systems, Series A: Mathematical Analysis".

Here's the simple answer - write it up, submit it, and find out!  If it is rejected, they usually say why.  If you are part of an academic organization (i.e., a student), then I would find a professor who would help you initially, and then find the right journal.  Otherwise, I would write it up.

Another thing you can do is find a mathematician on UpWork.  For my own paper that's what I did.  Trying to get someone to give you worthwhile feedback is hard.  If you find a professional mathematician who is willing to look at it, chances are they are just going to be critical, because you probably didn't word things the right way, and mathematicians tend to be incredibly pedantic.  Paying someone is helpful because then they are trying to make you successful, and will help you fix it up and word it in a way that makes sense, rather than just telling you that you are "wrong" just because you don't have the precision in terminology that a professional would.

Also note - there are many good ideas which, while not *new*, certainly could use re-explaining or just reminding everyone of them.  You can often get these published as education papers.  That is, you aren't claiming that it is new, you are talking about math education and how it can be improved by focusing on this idea, or that the idea can be better explained to students by going a different route than usual.

Comment: Great answer (+1) and congratulations on your paper.  I have taken the liberty of making a slight edit to your answer to highlight the main advice and provide a link you your paper (you were too modest to do so I see!).  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Super cool to hear an actual example and I'm glad there's merit to rediscovery. One of the commentors on this post recommended a book with several examples very close to a solution I posted written in 1924, and I won't be surprised if mine is not a new finding. That being said, this book was filled with identities and properties not listed on Wolfram/Wikipedia and I'm thoroughly surprised they're not being utilized in programs like Mathematica

Comment: @johnnyb I actually posted the write up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4240329/914955)! Forgive the math text...

Comment: @johnnyb Your paper is much interesting, specially in converting ode's ! did you make progress on it ? I am particularly interested in applying your method to a 3rd degree ode

Comment: @GCab - I have not really done much with it so far.  I usually just teach intro calculus to homeschoolers, so I'm not even that exposed to things it might be useful for.  My curiosity, however, lies in the dynamics of $\frac{d^2y}{d^2x}$ (i.e., the second differential of y divided by the second differential of x), which my notation allows for, but the typical notation does not.  But, again, I haven't had a lot of time to devote to it.

Comment: I see, Thanks anyway